# date in wordpress not working on my schedule

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello So I'm having an issue with one of my pages http://thinkgreenstone.com/register/schedule/

as you will see the first date is off I need it to be Febuary, 21st 2017 all the others are correct but the first one. Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
<?php
$date_format = get_option('date_format');
global $cpt_footer_scripts;
if ( !empty($args['day_bar_background_color']) ) {
    $cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__date-btn.active { background-color: {$args['day_bar_background_color']}; }";
}
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} h2.schedule__event { color: {$args['session_title_font_color']} !important; font-size: {$args['session_title_font_size']}; } ";
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__text { color: {$args['session_text_font_color']} !important; font-size: {$args['session_text_font_size']}; } ";
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__time { color: {$args['session_time_font_color']} !important; font-size: {$args['session_time_font_size']}; } ";
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__main-place { color: {$args['session_location_font_color']} !important; font-size: {$args['session_location_font_size']}; } ";
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__info .btn { color: {$args['session_button_font_color']} !important; font-size: {$args['session_button_font_size']}; background-color: {$args['session_button_background_color']}; border-color: {$args['session_button_background_color']};} ";
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .ares-select__item, #{$args['element_id']} .ares-select__popup { background-color: {$args['background_color']}; color: {$args['title_font_color']}; } ";
if (!empty($args['title_font_color'])) {
    $cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .ares-select::after { border-color: {$args['title_font_color']} {$args['title_font_color']} transparent transparent; } ";
}
if ( !empty($args['session_speaker_name_color']) ) {
    $cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__speaker-name, #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__speaker-hover { color: {$args['session_speaker_name_color']}; } ";
}
if ( !empty($args['session_speaker_name_font_size']) ) {
    $cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__speaker-name, #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__speaker-hover { font-size: {$args['session_speaker_name_font_size']}; } ";
}
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .ares-select { border-color: {$args['title_font_color']}; } ";
$cpt_footer_scripts[] = " #{$args['element_id']} .schedule__speaker-name { color: {$args['speaker_name_font_color']}; font-size: {$args['speaker_name_font_size']}; } ";
?>
<!-- schedule -->
<section class="schedule more-content" <?php echo $args['styles']['section']; ?> id="<?php echo $args['element_id']; ?>" data-max-items="<?php echo apply_filters('ef_schedule_sessions_max', 10); ?>">

    <!-- site__centered -->
    <div class="site__centered">

        <!-- site__title -->
        <?php if ( !empty($args['title']) ) { ?>
            <h2 class="site__title site__title_logo " <?php echo $args['styles']['title']; ?>>
                <!-- title_icon -->
                <?php if (!empty($args['title_icon']) ) { ?>
                    <span class="title_icon" <?php echo $args['styles']['title_icon']; ?>><i class="fa fa-<?php echo $args['title_icon']; ?>"></i></span>
                <?php } ?>
                <!-- /title_icon -->
                <?php echo $args['title']; ?>
                <?php if ( !empty($args['subtitle']) ) { ?>
                <span class="site__title-info" <?php echo $args['styles']['subtitle']; ?>><?php echo $args['subtitle']; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </h2>
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- /site__title -->

        <!-- schedule__date-btns -->
        <div class="schedule__date-btns">
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach( $args['dates'] as $date ) {
                $active = '';
                if ( $i == 0 ) { $active = 'active'; }
                $i++;
                ?>
            <a class="schedule__date-btn <?php echo $active; ?>" href="#" data-value="<?php echo $date->meta_value; ?>" <?php echo $args['styles']['day_bar']; ?>><?php echo date_i18n($date_format, $date->meta_value); ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /schedule__date-btns -->

        <!-- schedule__filters -->
        <div class="schedule__filters">
            <select name="main-venue" id="main-venue" class="schedule__filters-main-venue">
                <option value="0"><?php _e('Location', 'cpt'); ?></option>
                <?php foreach( $args['locations'] as $location ) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $location->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $location->name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <select name="Technology" id="technology" class="schedule__filters-technology">
                <option value="0"><?php _e('Track', 'cpt'); ?></option>
                <?php foreach( $args['labels'] as $labels ) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $labels->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $labels->name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- /schedule__filters -->

        <!-- schedule__items -->
        <div class="schedule__items more-content__wrapper"></div>
        <!-- /schedule__items -->

        <!-- schedule__btns -->
        <div class="schedule__btns">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn_4 more-content__btn"><span><?php _e('Load More', 'cpt'); ?></span></a>
            <?php
            $pages_links = get_option(cpt_Theme_Functions::LINKS_OPTION_NAME);
            if ( isset($pages_links['schedule']) && !empty($pages_links['schedule']) ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $pages_links['schedule']; ?>" class="btn btn_4"><span><?php echo $args['button_text']; ?></span></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /schedule__btns -->

    </div>
    <!-- /site__centered -->

</section>

<!-- schedule -->
```

Comment: No one will help you if you dont post related code snippets.